# Can I remove these posts supporting ceiling beams?

Tags: structural, beam, renovation

The house was built in 1964 and is a split level. The living room has these 3 beams on the ceiling (which do not extend past the far wall in the picture). I am hoping those are not structural. There are also the two white vertical beams. I want to remove these. Could those be structural?

Looking at the picture of the front of the house, these are located on the right side and don't extend to the garage side.

[image: Beams]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the total dimensions of the beams? Length, width, height

Comment: @Matthew dimensions are 25' x 3.5" x 11.5"

Comment: how did you measure the 11.5in "depth" of the beam? Are you certain it is not recessed into the ceiling drywall and perhaps even beyond? You'd have to poke around to get full depth, unless the top of the beam is indeed visible. Does the same apply to all beams?

Answer (score 3):

#### TL;DR:

Get an architect or structural engineer on site to make a fully qualified, license & livelihood depend on being right, assessment of the situation.

---

IIUC, the interior picture is the upper floor on the right hand side looking toward the stairs leading down to the front door.

With that in mind, I'd suggest that it's likely that the posts in question *are* structural. They seem to help carry whatever load may be on those beams down to the floor at the edge of the stairs. The 3rd beam is supported by the wall under it. Is there another wall directly below that one? That's a good clue that it's structural.

However, without the services of an architect or structural engineer looking at the plans (if available) or physically on site, the best you're going to get on line is a "best guess". If it were me, I wouldn't want to risk my roof collapsing on some well intentioned best guesses from some people on the other side of the internet.

Comment: The 3rd beam is actually not supported by a wall. It is between the exterior wall and that partial wall you see in the picture. That 3rd beam has no posts supporting it either.

Comment: Interesting. Not having a post under the far beam then, _points to_ this not being structural. Again, though @oilers128, don't bet your roof on best guesses from well meaning people on the internet!

Comment: The OP reported that the beam is 4x12x25'. In general a 4x12 is not good for more than 12' span. Thus i posit that the posts *are* structural or the beam itself is entirely decorative. Which one?

Comment: That _is_ the question, @Matthew. Since I'm not a licensed SE and I'm not on site, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about the brown beams and the white posts.

Whether the brown beams are structural or decorative is best determined by an engineer, but given it's a cathedral ceiling, my guess is they are structural and hold up the roof joists.

Otherwise the roof joists have to be hung from the centre "king" beam, which would appear partially exposed in your case, and the other beams might be added for decorative purposes.

As for posts, check what they are made of. Are they hollow or solid? Wood or MDF? Wood finish over round metal? How are they fastened to the beam and the floor (hangers, 9d/10d nails)?

Check what is ultimately bearing those posts. You may need to cut inspection holes. Check the crawl space / lower level. Look for blocking under that post in the lower level ceiling, etc... You might see double/triple 2x6 studs on foundation. Some homes have foundation slabs, some have slabs and foundation walls.

Beam span calculations may show that the posts are not load bearing, especially if the third beam (far right in picture) has no such support.

The post likely just serves the purpose of holding the partition walls, and provide no load bearing.

Comment: All good tips. Should the OP expect to find joist hangers on a house built in 1964, though? Not sure when those really came into common use/code required.

Comment: @FreeMan I don't know, but if there is a framing grade hanger nailed with 10d, then it's a hint. I take it all as a bunch of hints. My guess is the brown beams are supported by multiple studs at their ends and the white posts are not required for the roof. Ultimately a framing carpenter/engineer needs to provide a definitive answer.